# Why Shinyapps.io not render RMarkdown document?

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, shinyapps

I deploy on shinyapps.io application where for one-page loading text from RMarkdown document. It works fine on a local computer but shows an empty screen on shinyapps.io

Here is Rmarkdown file

```
---
title: ""
runtime: shiny
output: html_document
---

# Demo

This demo text
```

Here is Shiny app code

```
  # Text
  output$uo_demo_text <- renderUI({
    HTML(htmltools::includeMarkdown("text/demo.Rmd"))
  })
```

Any helps are welcome!